# 2D HTML5 Canvas Game: Specific width/height restricts player movement (No collision implemented)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-development

## Q: Why is movement restricted in these directions depending on the canvas' width/height + player position, and how do I fix this?

As mentioned in the title I have been building a 2D canvas game (a top-down creature collector like Pokémon), and **without implementing any collision** there is a mysterious bug.

The bug is stopping my character from moving in two directions depending on character starting position and the canvas' width/height even though I am able to move to some tiles in these directions before being stopped:

- Up / Right

or

- Left / Down

***This only happens when the canvas' width/height are set to specific values, and I'm able to still move as far as I want in the two directions not affected.***

My desired width & height are 360x240 to display the map's 24x24 pixel tiles 15 across the width, and 10 across the height. When attempting to use 720x480 (2x the desired dimensions), and 300x200 the movement **was not restricted**.

Here is a link to the repo for the bug if you would like to test it out: https://github.com/LateSupper/CreatureCollectorBug

I've included two maps of varied sizes to test this issue with inside of the "engine.js" file. Just have to switch which one you'd like to test.

And here is an image of where the invisible diagonal barrier seems to be in the example I have in the repo:
[Invisible Barrier Visual (Player starts on the yellow square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyWvi.png)

Things I've tried include:

- Console logging movement logic to see if it still fires (it does, but no movement)
- Setting the canvas' width/height to various dimensions with differing results and mostly having 3:2 aspect ratio dimensions failing to allow movements in those directions
- Created different maps which by my code's logic changes the starting position of the player, and changes which two directions are blocked
- **Googling**. Of course I Googled the heck out of this today because why would this even happen? Oddest bug I've ever encountered with an HTML Canvas game.

**edit:** Per recommendation of adding code I think may be causing my troubles:

```
// "main.js" -> line 1
const game = new GameEngine(
  { width: 24 * 16, height: 24 * 10 }, // Dimensions
  24, // Tile Size
  18 // Camera Offset
)
```

In the above code when the width and/or height is multiplied by an odd number movement is restricted, but if both numbers are ***24 * an even number*** it works perfectly fine.

Would this potentially be an issue of how I am drawing the background/player sprites onto the canvas?:

```
// "engine.js" -> GameEngine.determineSpriteProperties()
determineSpriteProperties = (image) => {
  const properties = {
    type: 0,
    position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    image: image
  }
  if (image.currentSrc.indexOf("map_") > -1) {
    properties.position.x = ((this.canvas.width / 2) - (image.width / 2)) + (this.tileSize / 2),
    properties.position.y = ((this.canvas.height / 2) - (image.height / 2))
  } else {
    properties.type = 1
    properties.position.x = (this.canvas.width / 2 - (image.width / 3)) + ((image.width / 3) / 2)
    properties.position.y = this.canvas.height / 2 - (image.height / 4) + this.cameraOffset
  }
  return properties
}
```

Comment: To get a good answer here it would help if you paste the exact code here that is giving you problems, instead of a link to the whole project. One of the problems in your code seems to be a complicated list of nested `if` statements in the movement controller. This becomes a bit spaghetti code and is often the cause of unexpected results. Once you find out where exactly your bug is you can focus your question a bit better.

Comment: @Kokodoko OK I added some code I think may be the culprit(s).

Comment: I sent you a PR on github:
https://github.com/LateSupper/CreatureCollectorBug/pull/1/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the condition to stop the movement...
You had an `if` statement:

```
this.mapSprite.position.x !== this.targetPosition.position && 
this.mapSprite.position.y !== this.targetPosition.position
```

... but the `targetPosition` also has an axis property that you did not include in the that condition

```
(targetPosition.axis == "x" && mapSprite.position.x !== targetPosition.position) ||
(targetPosition.axis == "y" && mapSprite.position.y !== targetPosition.position)
```

*( I removed some code to make this sample small )*

---

See my PR for details:
https://github.com/LateSupper/CreatureCollectorBug/pull/1

Comment: I appreciate the help and the PR! Do you have any advice as to how I could refactor the code and make it less of a mess?

Comment: @Undwell recommendation for future questions... you need to reduce the code in your sample code, on this problem for example the sprites was not an issue just a distraction from what really is the problem, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  even in the process of reducing the code we often find the problem

Comment: Great advice. I'll take that into consideration for future questions.

Comment: @Undwell for making it less of a mess ?!?  maybe adopt a true game engine: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Comment: With the type of project I'm working on do you have a recommendation from that list?

Comment: there are advantages and disadvantages, it is 100% up to you... look at what games are built with each and see if you find something like yours

Comment: I could add that if your game has a lot of moving and colliding elements, you almost always need a 2D physics engine. The simplest way is to add "matter.js" as a collision detection engine to your game. Or you could learn a whole game engine. I think Excalibur is the most easy to learn. Phaser is also cool but requires a very specific way of programming.